# How can I align BarMarks in SwiftUI Charts?

Tags: swiftui, charts

SwiftUI Charts by default take up the entire available width and divides the space between the BarMarks.
This code renders the following chart

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "A"),
                    y: .value("Rating", 100),
                    width: 3.0)
            BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "B"),
                    y: .value("Rating", 150),
                    width: 3.0)
        }
        .frame(height:200)
    }
}
```

[image]

My desired result is this

[image]

It's not possible to wrap the BarMarks in a HStack with a Spacer, and I haven't found anything in [`.chartXAxis{}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartxaxis(content:)) that would allow this.

Is it possible to align the BarMarks? So far my only working method is to change the frame width based on the number of BarMarks that are displayed, but that is a very cumbersome method.

Comment: You don't draw a bar chart like that with all that empty space between the last bar and the y axis. The only time you have empty space is when there are no values yet but you would still have the marks on the x axis, C, D, E, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joakim Danielson pointed out, it's not possible to align the barmarks by default this way. I ended up adding a certain amount of BarMarks with y values of 0. That way they aren't visible, but do take up exactly the amount of space that I want.
This is a minimal sample of the code

```
Chart {
    BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "A"),
            yStart: .value("Rating", 0),
            yEnd:   .value("Rating", 100))
    BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "B"),
            yStart: .value("Rating", 0),
            yEnd:   .value("Rating", 150))
    
    BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "C"),
            yStart: .value("Rating", 0),
            yEnd:   .value("Rating", 0))
            
    BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "D"),
            yStart: .value("Rating", 0),
            yEnd:   .value("Rating", 0))
            
    BarMark(x: .value("Item",  "E"),
            yStart: .value("Rating", 0),
            yEnd:   .value("Rating", 0))
}
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(position: .bottom) { _ in
        AxisValueLabel().foregroundStyle(.clear)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: threre seem to be a minimum of 6 bars to align center and distribute. Otherwise it compresses the bars on a side.

Comment: That's incorrect @jalone, even a chart with just 1 bar will take up all width if you don't specify the bar-width.  Apple's documentation displays how a 3-bar chart will align and equally distribute all space: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/barmark

Comment: What if you specify the width? I can replicate my issue with various configurations, i think it's a Charts bug, but i don't have it at hand atm.